# python subprocess.Popen.stderr hanging

Tags: python, subprocess, infinite-loop

I have the following python code in a script.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("test.bat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if len(proc.stderr.read()) > 0:
    #Do stuff
```

The line with the if statement isn't throwing any errors, but is instead just hanging indefinitely like it's in an infinite loop. Any ideas on why this be happening?

FYI, here's the script that I'm calling, which is in the same directory.

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

EDIT:
I commented out the above lines and added in :

```
output = proc.stdout.read()
```

This line is now hanging in the same fashion as the above one.  Additionally all the various file functions to read from the file hang in the same fashion.

Comment: I suspect you need to read stdout rather than stderr

Comment: Do the error messages go to stdout?  I thought they went to stderr.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the script didn't just have the echo in it, it also had a pause at the beginning that was screwing everything up.